# AFC Toolbox and converting pfiles to mfiles

Tags: matlab

Has anyone ever worked with AFC toolbox?
Is there a way to convert pfiles to mfiles?

Comment: Is [this](http://medi.uni-oldenburg.de/afc/) the tool that the OP is interested in?

Comment: A question that has surely been asked many tomes before.

Comment: @woodchips I preferred tome 1 :-)

Comment: @ David Gorsline :it is related to psychoacoustic stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never heard of the AFC toolbox, and no, you cannot reverse-engineer p-coded files back into MATLAB files, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/protect-your-source-code.html for more details.